# Select rows where column1, column2, column3 and column4 != 1

Tags: sql, operators

I'm trying to make a website that shows what score a employee got from a customer. The data looks like this

```
Name | wait|service |solution | total | date
joe     1     1          1        1      2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
joe     1     3          5        4      2018-09-02 00:00:00.000
joe     5     5          5        5      2018-09-03 00:00:00.000
joe     3     1          5        3      2018-09-04 00:00:00.000
joe     3     1          1        3      2018-09-05 00:00:00.000
joe     1     5          3        1      2018-09-06 00:00:00.000
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make a select query that excludes rows where wait,service, solution and total are 1.

I thought at first that `where wait != 1 and service !=1 and solution != 1 and total != 1` would work. But that excludes all records that contains 1, and it was obvious when I executed the query and saw the result.

But is there any "easy" wait to exclude rows where the four columns are all 1s?

So when i execute the query it would look like this

```
Name | wait|service |solution | total | date  
joe     1     3          5        4      2018-09-02 00:00:00.000
joe     5     5          5        5      2018-09-03 00:00:00.000
joe     3     1          5        3      2018-09-04 00:00:00.000
joe     3     1          1        3      2018-09-05 00:00:00.000
joe     1     5          3        1      2018-09-06 00:00:00.000
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Count sum of the four columns and list only records with sum greater than 4?

Comment: @StefanR: We cannot take the sum of columns blindly. What if the values are 1,0,1,2? Sum for columns will still be 4, but it should not be excluded from the result.

Comment: Please explain why `where wait != 1 and service !=1 and solution != 1 and total != 1` does not work.  That appears to be the logic you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NOT` can sometimes make it easier:

```
WHERE NOT (wait = 1 AND service = 1 AND solution = 1 AND total = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Just change your logic to `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
select * 
from TableName
where Wait<>1 or Service<>1 or solution<>1 or total<>1
```

If all 4 fields are having value 1 then the condition in where clause will return `false` which would result the record to be excluded from the result.

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db1a05c/1).

Comment: Thanks that worked beautifully! I thought or wouldn't work so I never tried it. But now I know

Comment: @JeanFredrikLeirtrø: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE
 (COLUMN_1 + COLUMN_2 + COLUMN_3 + COLUMN_4) <> 4
OR
(COLUMN_1 = COLUMN_2
 AND COLUMN_2 = COLUMN_3
 AND COLUMN_3 = COLUMN_4
 AND COLUMN_4 <> 1);
```

Comment: That seems pretty convoluted.